# Dynamic input shape of layer in TensorFlow 2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

How to define a layer that can handle different input shape?
It looks like this:

```
# dynamic_input_shape_conv_layer is a tf.keras layer
input_1 (None, 32, 32, 3) => dynamic_input_shape_conv_layer => (None, 32, 32, 6)
input_1 (None, 32, 32, 2) => dynamic_input_shape_conv_layer => (None, 32, 32, 6)
```

Is that possible to achieve this in TensorFlow 2.x?